# What's the deal with ace & pip?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

In Combinatorial Game Theory by Aaron Siegel on page 298 the games ace, deuce & trey are introduced:
$$\text{ace}=\{0|+_\text{on}\}$$
$$\text{deuce}=\{0|\text{ace}\}$$
$$\text{trey}=\{0|\text{deuce}\}$$
The book proceeds to assert that "in general":
$$\text{pip}_0=+_\text{on}$$
$$\text{pip}_{\text{n}+1}=\{0|\text{pip}_\text{n}\}$$
Additionally, the following relations are given:
$$\text{ace}+\text{ace}=\text{deuce}$$
$$\text{deuce}+\text{ace}=\text{trey}$$
$$n\cdot\text{ace}=\text{pip}_n (n\geq1)$$
After that, not much else is said about these games. My primary questions are:

A) **What is pip?**

B) **How does ace compare to $+_\text{on}$?** (Is it smaller, larger, equal or fuzzy? I would guess it's smaller, but I have read elsewhere that $+_\text{on}$ is the smallest of all games.)

C) **What is the infimum/supremum of $\{\text{ace, deuce, trey,...}\}$?** (My best guess is $\text{pip}_\text{on}$, however I'm unclear if this sequence is increasing or decreasing.)

Comment: A "pip" is a dot on a die.  One side has one pip, another two pips, ... up to six pips.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The relevant definition from Oxford Dictionary is [this one](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pip#h70282991909600): "Any of the spots on playing cards, dice, or dominoes." which includes playing cards, as in the naming convention for these games.

Comment: OK.  Sure.  Dice and other playing objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is pip?

The terminology here comes from words related to playing cards in a [standard 52-card deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck). Specifically, [English nicknames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck#English_pattern_cards_and_nicknames), where "ace", "duece", and "trey" refer to the cards with one, two, and three symbols respectively. Those symbols are called "pips" (see [this Oxford dictionary entry](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pip#h70260549027000) with the definition "Any of the spots on playing cards, dice, or dominoes."). The notation is suggestive of $\mathbf{pip}_n$ being a playing card with $n$ symbols on it. This comes from an extended playing card metaphor (introduced by the late John Horton Conway?) in the combinatorial game theory text [Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_Ways_for_your_Mathematical_Plays) (often abbreviated "Winning Ways").

## How does $\mathbf{ace}$ compare to $+_{\mathbf{on}}$?

It's not hard to show that $\mathbf{ace}>0$. No matter if Left moves first or second, she wins by making the only available move. Then Proposition 2.12 on page 297 says we must have $\mathbf{ace}\ge +_{\mathbf{on}}$ ($+_{\mathbf{on}}$ is the smallest positive game).
Since $\mathbf{ace}\ne +_{\mathbf{on}}$, $\mathbf{ace}> +_{\mathbf{on}}$.

## What is the infinimum/supremum of $\{\mathbf{ace},\mathbf{deuce},\mathbf{trey},\dots\}$?

Firstly, $\mathbf{pip}_G$ has not been defined for games $G$, so $\mathbf{pip}_{\mathbf{on}}$ doesn't really make sense. We only have $\mathbf{pip}_n$ for nonnegative integers $n$.

Since we have $\mathbf{ace}<\mathbf{deuce}<\cdots$, the minimum of your set is $\mathbf{ace}$, so that's the infimum.

The supremum is $\mathbf{over}=\{0\mid\mathbf{pass}\}$. You can guess this by looking at the trees for the $\mathbf{pip}_n$ in Figure 2.5. And one way to check it is from $\mathrm{aw}(\mathbf{pip}_n)=n$ on p299 and $\mathbf{over}=\sup_n(\uparrow n)$.

## Calculating these things

As an aside, you can calculate with these pips using version [0.7 of Combinatorial Game Suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cgsuite/files/cgsuite/older/0.7%20beta/) and the loopy game notation described [here on cgsuite.org](http://www.cgsuite.org/docs/tutorials/using-cgsuite/loopygames.html). For examples, you could use a command like `tiny:={0|{0|off}};ace:={0|tiny};ace+ace>ace` to confirm that $\mathbf{deuce}>\mathbf{ace}$, and it knows that `a:{0|a}` is $\mathbf{over}$.

Comment: I had tried the newest version of CGS & couldn't get it to work. Got the version you linked to working - thanks for that. As a (hopefully comment sized) follow-up: do you know how $\uparrow$ & ace relate? (I'm aware that both have an atomic weight of 1, but am not sure what $n$ would equal in something like $n\cdot\uparrow=\text{ace}$ or $\uparrow=n\cdot\text{ace}$). Re: "We only have $\text{pip}_n$ for nonnegative integers $n$" - I'm guessing then that there isn't already something like $\text{pip}_\omega$? If not, is it (logically) possible to do so?

Comment: Additionally, what is the supremum of $+_n$? Is it also **over**? I can ask any of these comment questions as new questions if the answers exceed what is sensible for a comment.

Comment: @user784623 Both of your questions can be answered very quickly by reviewing earlier material in "Combinatorial Game Theory". Answering questions like these might do you a disservice - if you take more time to focus on the prerequisite material, then you would have many of your answers and be poised to find most of the rest quickly on your own. The intended audience of the section of the text we're discussing would know basically immediately that "supremum of $\pmb{+}_n$" is a boring/the wrong question, from prior familiarity with suprema and $\pmb{+}_n$. And the infimum is on the page...

Comment: @user784623 I don't know your math background in detail, but the questions you're asking and the way you're asking them suggest that you may not be able to use a graduate level text like Siegel's "Combinatorial Game Theory" efficiently yet. I would encourage you to start with "Lessons in Play: An Introduction to Combinatorial Game Theory" by Albert, Nowakowski, and Wolfe or "An Introduction to Combinatorial Game Theory" by Haff and Garner. On the off chance this section of Siegel is your first introduction to the words "supremum" and "infimum" in mathematics, definitely study real analysis.