# Can we topple the surreal house of cards?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

In [Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_Ways_for_Your_Mathematical_Plays) , Volume 2 , there is a section "The House of Cards" which contains figure 18 "Plumtrees in the Uplands" which shows the game trees for (in respective order) $\text{off, oof, tiny, ace, duece & trey}$ .

We know that [$\text{tiny} < \text{ace} < \text{deuce}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3664359/1252699) ... & $\text{off} < \text{tiny}$ makes sense to me. But what about $\text{oof}$ ?

$$\text{oof}=\{0|\text{off}\}$$

The book says "the thermograph of $\text{oof}$ [..] shows it to be less than all positive numbers, but confused with all the others".

It seems like $\text{oof}$ is a positive value ( based on the left set being $0$ ), but the game tree seems to imply it is smaller than $\text{tiny}$ & this seems to be confirmed with the thermograph showing it to be less than all positive numbers.

**Is $\text{oof}$ a positive game whose value is < $\text{tiny}$ ?**

If so, this would topple ( Contradict ) the idea that $\text{tiny}$ is the smallest game value.

My suspicion is that $\text{tiny}$ is the smallest game value for some class of games (I'm not well versed in game classes) & $\text{oof}$ is the smallest in some other (loopy?) class.

Comment: These are Non-Standard Numbers , where we can have multiple $0$ values , something between $0$ & "Smallest Positive Number" & ETC. It then looks like "oof" is between $0$ & "tiny" .... Thinking !!

Comment: A good question begins by giving minimum context like "Winning Ways is a 3 volumes book by Conway dealing with games"

Comment: Oh , 3 is the average of 2 & 4 , @JeanMarie , your typo might have some hidden meaning.

Comment: Check Page 100 figure 21 , where we can see Positive Numbers & Negative Numbers & a whole lot of fuzzy numbers. It looks like $\text{oof}$ is a fuzzy number near $0$ : While $\text{oof}$ is not positive , it is less than all Positive Numbers !

Comment: @JeanMarie I feel like the combinatorial-game-theory tag kind of makes any mention of Winning Ways enough. If you can answer question in that tag, you very likely know what is being referred to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OVER-VIEW :**

We can see that $\text{oof}$ is less than all Positive Values , but it itself is not Positive.
The smallest Positive Value is $\text{tiny}$ , which is strictly/necessarily less than $\text{ace}$.
The House of Cards has not toppled !

I will use that Book itself to cover the various Points :

**Page 353 :**

> $\text{tiny} = +_{on}$
> tiny is the smallest positive value there is!
> Of course , $\text{miny} = -_{on} = -\text{tiny}$ is the least negative game there is.

**Page 357 :**

[ Images have my high-lighting ]

[image: off oof]

[image: Partial list]

We see here that $\text{oof}$ is very close to $\text{off}$ neither of which is Positive , while $\text{tiny}$ & upwards are Positive.
In other words , $\text{oof}$ is less than all Positive Values , though it itself is not Positive.

**Page 360 :**

[image: Positive Negative]

Here we see that $\text{tiny}$ & $\text{miny}$ fall outside the fuzzy range , where the Values are neither Positive nor Negative.
It is in this range that we have $\text{oof}$ , which is less than all Positive Values.

**Page 454 :**

The Connection between $\text{off}$ & $\text{oof}$ & $\text{tiny}$ is given in the glossary :

[image: Equality Connection]

**SUMMARY :**

We can see that $\text{oof}$ is less than all Positive Values , but it itself is not Positive.
The smallest Positive Value is $\text{tiny}$ , which is strictly/necessarily less than $\text{ace}$.
The House of Cards has not toppled !

Comment: "which is like 0" makes it sound like off is like 0 in some relevant way. But off is the most negative value so I would think of it as quite unlike 0. Could you clarify (or omit) that part? (Also I wouldn't call tiny a number, though Owen would.)

Comment: I updated it , @MarkS. , thank you !

Comment: About terminology : when adding & comparing these "things" , we can use game , value , number , etc , @MarkS. , though my force of habit makes me use number !

Comment: Amazing answer! Give me some time to think-

Comment: @Prem, I disagree that we can safely use "number" in that way, because calling all game positions/values "numbers" conflicts badly with the usage in Winning Ways. Many theorems in Winning Ways that refer to numbers, like Number Avoidance (proved on page 183), very intentionally do *not* apply to game (positions) that aren't surreal numbers, to say nothing of loopy positions. (It specifically says that "$G$ is not a number".) (As an aside, modern texts like Siegel's Combinatorial Game Theory do a better job at distinguishing game positions from their values, and I think that's good, too.)

Comment: Would it be better to change "number" to "value" or "game" , @MarkS. , though-out my Post ? It seems to be Non-Standardized , Eg https://senseis.xmp.net/?SurrealNumbers , through informal usages !

Comment: Again, really quality answer! I think my intuition for this is slowly starting to improve. It seems like oof represents the 'set' of negative numbers w/ a 'tiny' slice $\le$ tiny (compared to off which seems to represent a type of negative infinity). 
Re: language, I think i will start using value more ‍♀️

Comment: Critical Inputs from @MarkS. were very useful too , which made me know more , to improve my Answer appropriately !

Comment:  @MarkS. (imho) is 1 of the top contributors to the surreal / cgt space on stackexchange 

Comment: @Prem "Would it be better to change "number" to "value" or "game" through-out my Post?" That happens to be the case, yes. But it wasn't obvious that it would from only statements taken from Winning Ways. Specifically, Winning Ways says that oof is less than all positive (surreal) *numbers*, but you need to do a little work to check that oof<tiny to be sure that oof is less than all positive positions/games/values. (I just did, but you shouldn't take my word for it.)

Comment: @Prem - off topic, but u seem to be into surreals ‍♀️ so i thought i would share: https://hypersurreal.github.io/_/

Comment: It is fantastic , @hypersurreal , that will take a while to Process !

Comment: @Prem Unfortunately, most of the sunny and loony pages at that link are "[not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong)" in that they combine symbols in ways that known theorems (probably even in ONAG) say cannot end very well, and do not define those combinations of symbols.

Comment: I realized that , @MarkS. , which was why [[ like Conway used https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=oneiric ]] I used the most appropriate word [[ https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=fantastic ]] in that Comment , to make it gentle !

Answer (score 3):

> less than all positive numbers, but confused with all the others

This means that if $x>0$ is a number then $\mathrm{oof}<x$, and that if $x\le0$ is a number then $\mathrm{oof}\parallel x$. In particular, this is saying that $\mathrm{oof}\parallel0$ so, **no**, $\mathrm{oof}$ is not positive.

> It seems like $\mathrm{oof}$
> is a positive value ( based on the left set being $0$ )

Even outside the context of loopy games, that can easily fail as soon as the game is not a number. For example, $*\cong\{0\mid0\}$ is not positive.

Comment: I appreciate the answer & I think it makes sense - just want to give it a little time to digest before I accept. As a follow up, how would u evaluate {0|tiny}? (Im not sure if that is worth posting as a question or not ‍♀️)

Comment: @hypersurreal The pages of Winning Ways describing these cards tells you that $\{0\mid\mathrm{tiny}\}$ is the definition of "ace" (also the question you linked). And the answer of mine you link in your question tells you that it's bigger than tiny.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written that differently. Do you know of any values that satisfy 0 < x < tiny? (I still find small games kind of counter intuitive - but my intuition as to *why* that is seems to be improving)

Comment: @hypersurreal On page 353, Winning Ways correctly says that tiny is less than any other positive game. So there are no such x (tus justifying Conway's name "tiny").

Comment: I was wondering if u wouldn't mind taking a look at the "map" I created: https://hypersurreal.github.io/_/%E2%8A%99/ - I know that's very hypothetical (& u may hate it ). I just really appreciate your perspective ‍♀️

Comment: @hypersurreal I wish you would take the time to walk before running off a cliff, so to speak. But I am also happy to see your enthusiasm for games. Many things on that page are not typically defined for good reason, and if you're going to write things like 1/tiny you should 1. take the time to understand why even 1/↑ is not typically defined (I am aware that [Conway wrote it once but he did not define it and may have been making a joke](https://mathoverflow.net/q/360258/28209)) 2. Give a precise definition of what you mean, and ideally 3. Have a justification for why it's worth defining at all

Comment: I know u do.. unfortunately I think I passed the event horizon (fell off the cliff) some time ago  I am indeed enthusiastic to learn more about surreals tho! Re: why things are not typically defined - I suspect it's context. Perhaps my area of interest lies in what may not be  "games" (eg. 2 player sequential perfect information games). I haven't seen much that talked about puzzles (1 player games) or cellular automatons (0 player games) wrt surreals. I imagine there is interesting maths in those realms tho (& maybe even in abstract realms like $\emptyset$ or * player games) ‍♀️

Comment: @hypersurreal "[why things are not defined] I suspect it's context" Your suspicion is badly wrong. A single product proves that multiplication as defined for surreals doesn't respect equality of games outside of major restrictions like "only the surreals" or "only nimbers". -- If you truly feel like you have passed an event horizon and are incapable of going back to study the basics on a firm foundation, but would also like people to be interested in your thoughts on mathematics, then I would encourage you to seek therapy; I suspect you're capable of more than you think with the right support.